# Is it possible to force dvips to produce an EPS with %%HiResBoundingBox header?

Tags: dvips, bounding-box

Invoking the following command

```
dvips input.dvi -E -o output.eps
```

will produce an EPS file with only `%%BoundingBox` header as follows:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%BoundingBox: 85 626 184 729
```

Unfortunately this bounding box is not so accurate that it cannot be imported by 
`\includegraphics[hiresbb]{output.eps}`.

Shortly speaking, is it possible to force dvips to produce not only `%%BoundingBox` but also `%%HiResBoundingBox`?

Actually we can insert `%%HiResBoundingBox` using `epstool --copy --bbox input.eps output.eps`, but I want to minimize the workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to generate an accurate bounding box with the -E option, the reason why a hires bb is also not possible.